# React native Image with no fixed size not showing in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, react-native-flatlist, image-size

React native Image with no fixed size not showing in FlatList But if I used it outside of the FlatList it will work fine with the original size of the image

I’m using style for the image
{flex:1, resizeMode:”contain”}

I don’t want to us Image.getSize
Because it fails sometimes leaving the image with no size and it takes time making the image take longer to load.

I want to let the image get its original size in the FlatList, I’m looking for a solution for several days so If anyone have a solution, I will be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.